# Android - TouchImageView Full view issue

Tags: java, android, android-fullscreen, touchimageview

In my application am able to load all the images from server(using volley library) and showing in grid view.

See the Grid view:
[image]

but when I click on particular item(Image) from gallery it's not able to show in full view but the things are working fine like zoom, pinch and swipe etc..

This is my [TouchImageView.java](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/ortiz/touch/TouchImageView.java) Code

FullScreenImageAdapter.java:

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

    import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;


    public class FullScreenImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        private Activity _activity;
        private ArrayList<String> _imagePaths;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        // constructor
        public FullScreenImageAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> imagePaths) {
            this._activity = activity;
            this._imagePaths = imagePaths;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return this._imagePaths.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            TouchImageView imgDisplay;
            Button btnClose;

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) _activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fullscreen_image, container, false);

            imgDisplay = (TouchImageView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);
            btnClose = (Button) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.btnClose);

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            options.inSampleSize = 4;

            // Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_imagePaths.get(position),
            // options);
            // imgDisplay.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            // Loading image with placeholder and error image
            ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
            String path = _imagePaths.get(position);
            imageLoader.get(path, ImageLoader.getImageListener(imgDisplay, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.logo_final));

            // close button click event
            btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    _activity.finish();
                }
            });

            ((ViewPager) container).addView(viewLayout);

            return viewLayout;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

        }

    }
```

FullScreenViewActivity.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class FullScreenViewActivity extends Activity {

    // private Utils utils;
    private FullScreenImageAdapter adapter;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_view);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        // utils = new Utils(getApplicationContext());

        Intent i = getIntent();
        int position = i.getIntExtra("position", 0);
        ArrayList<String> imagePaths = i.getExtras().getStringArrayList("imagePaths");

        adapter = new FullScreenImageAdapter(FullScreenViewActivity.this, imagePaths);

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        // displaying selected image first
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
    }
}
```

activity_fullscreen_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.example.test.adapter.ExtendedViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

layout_fullscreen_image.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <com.example.test.util.TouchImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgDisplay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/splash_screen_final" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClose"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:text="@string/close"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

ExtendedViewPager.java:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;


public class ExtendedViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public ExtendedViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ExtendedViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean canScroll(View v, boolean checkV, int dx, int x, int y) {
        if (v instanceof TouchImageView) {
            //
            // canScrollHorizontally is not supported for Api < 14. To get around this issue,
            // ViewPager is extended and canScrollHorizontallyFroyo, a wrapper around
            // canScrollHorizontally supporting Api >= 8, is called.
            //
            return ((TouchImageView) v).canScrollHorizontallyFroyo(-dx);

        } else {
            return super.canScroll(v, checkV, dx, x, y);
        }
    }

}
```

touchimageview:
[image]

Any suggestion could be appreciated.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: I think in layout_fullscreen_image.xml layout_height is set to wrap_content try using fill_parent

Comment: Yeah bro tried but no use..thanks for your suggestion..

Comment: Any suggestions please..?

Comment: try using android:scaleType="matrix" instead of  android:scaleType="fitXY" and android:layout_height="fill_parent" to parent layout of Touchimageview

Comment: OK I'll try and let you know.

Comment: As you told I changed   `android:scaleType="fitXY"`  to `android:scaleType="matrix"` And  `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`  but same result.. Not able to see full view in `layout_fullscreen_image.xml` @RajeshJadav

Comment: can u add screenshot of full image (touchimageview)?

Comment: Yes I am getting a default image in full screen see attached image above..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the problem is with URL encoding finally I got the solution.

I just added this line bafore sending imagePaths to `FullScreenViewActivity` to make it work.

> imagePathsString.add(uri.toString());